# What wall material should be used behind the Kerdi system in a tub/shower?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, tile

I know from my [previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/what-kind-of-wall-material-should-be-used-in-wet-areas-in-a-bathroom) that in most cases a cement board of some kind needs to be used. However, when the Kerdi membrane system is being used behind the tile, is it still necessary to use a cement backer board?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Schluter says that behind the Kerdi membrane a solid backing needs to be used.  They define a solid backing as :

- gypsum wallboard
- cementitious backer unit
- fibercement underlayment
- fiber-reinforced water-resistant
  gypsum
- backerboard/underlayment
- coated glass mat water-resistant
  gypsum
- backerboard
- portland cement mortar bed
- concrete
- masonry

Found this in their Shower System Installation Handbook here.
Link : http://www.schluter.com/media/ShowerHandbook.pdf

Comment: Add a link to the source of this info to make this the perfect answer.